# data.table: Create new character column based on indicator columns values and names

Tags: r, data.table, calculated-columns, dcast

I have a data.table with 1.6x10^8 records and I want to create a new character column based on the indicator column names for where there is a value of 1.

For example,

```r
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table::data.table(ID=c("a","a","a","b","b"),
                             drugA=c(1,1,1,0,0),
                             drugB=c(0,1,1,1,0),
                             drugC=c(0,0,1,0,1))

   ID drugA drugB drugC
1:  a     1     0     0
2:  a     1     1     0
3:  a     1     1     1
4:  b     0     1     0
5:  b     0     0     1

### NOTE: I know the paste0(...,collapse) argument might be helpful in concatenating the drug names as an intermediate step
   ID drugA drugB drugC          exposure
1:  a     1     0     0             drugA
2:  a     1     1     0       drugA+drugB
3:  a     1     1     1 drugA+drugB+drugC
4:  b     0     1     0             drugB
5:  b     0     0     1             drugC
```

I want this to be as robust as clean as possible and solely rely on data.table syntax and/or other useful packages/functions (e.g. dcast) ; I want to steer away from creating an extensive user-defined function because given my data.table size, it would take extremely long to run.

I've looked at other posts but I was unable to find something similar to my situation and desired output.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do a group by sequence of rows, specify the `.SDcols` as the 'drug' column, convert the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`) to `logical`, use that to subset the column names and `paste` them together

```
library(data.table)
DT[,  exposure := paste(names(.SD)[as.logical(.SD)], collapse= '+'), 
       1:nrow(DT), .SDcols = drugA:drugC]
DT
#   ID drugA drugB drugC          exposure
#1:  a     1     0     0             drugA
#2:  a     1     1     0       drugA+drugB
#3:  a     1     1     1 drugA+drugB+drugC
#4:  b     0     1     0             drugB
#5:  b     0     0     1             drugC
```

---

Or instead of grouping by rows, we can loop over the columns, change the values to column names and then `paste` with `do.call` and remove the `NA` elements with `gsub`

```
DT[, exposure := gsub("NA\\+|\\+NA", "", do.call(paste, 
   c(Map(function(x, y) names(.SD)[(NA^!x) * y], .SD, 
   seq_along(.SD)), sep="+"))), .SDcols = drugA:drugC]
```

Comment: @theneil i added one more optioin that should be faster than the first

Comment: your first code post took ~25 minutes to run and your second code post tookd ~10 minutes. This was on 1.6x10^8 rows of data. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
library('data.table')
DT[, id := .I]
df <- melt(DT, id.vars = 'id', measure.vars = c("drugA", "drugB", "drugC"))
df[value == 1, expose := 'exposure']
df[value == 0, expose := 'no_exposure'][, value := NULL]
df <- dcast(df, id ~ expose, fun.aggregate = function(x) paste0(x, collapse = "+"), value.var = 'variable')
DT[df, on = 'id'][, id := NULL][]
#    ID drugA drugB drugC          exposure no_exposure
# 1:  a     1     0     0             drugA drugB+drugC
# 2:  a     1     1     0       drugA+drugB       drugC
# 3:  a     1     1     1 drugA+drugB+drugC            
# 4:  b     0     1     0             drugB drugA+drugC
# 5:  b     0     0     1             drugC drugA+drugB
```